# How to make flutter post request with parameter in url like a get request

Tags: dart, flutter

I try to make a post call with flutter http. the thing is there is some datas passed to my url like something/xxxxx?log=yyy&ref=dd.
When i try the request on postman the request work but when i try in the code it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Call post api with parameters, for me work fine:

```
Future<http.Response> callMe(String id, String name) async {

  final param = {
    "id": id,
    "name": name,
  };

  final response = await http.post(
    "yourURL",  // change with your url
    body: param,
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print("OK!");
  }
  else {
    print('Error!');
    return null;
  }

  return response;
}
```

Call onPressed

```
onPressed: ()
                  {
                    callMe('100','stackoverflow');
                  },
```